# Segmentation fault during running unit test cases using Vitest

Tags: node.js, segmentation-fault, vuejs3, vitest

I am on the Windows 10 operating system using Git Bash. I am using the v18.18.0 node version and the 9.8.1 npm version. The project is implemented in the Vue.js framework using the 3.3.4 version. For testing purposes, the `vitest` testing framework executes the unit test cases. The scripts' content of the `package.json` file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vite",
    "test:unit": "vitest",
    "coverage": "vitest run --coverage",
  },
```

When I ran the `npm run test:unit` command, I got the segmentation fault error.

```
 ✓ src/views/__tests__/SockView.spec.js (3)
   ✓ StockView.vue (3)
     ✓ renders a title
     ✓ does not render the Bar chart when not loaded
     ✓ renders the Bar chart when loaded
/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 64:   321 Segmentation fault      "$NODE_EXE" "$NPM_CLI_JS" "$@"
```

As you can see all tests passed but there is a segmentation fault error at the end of the test run. After that, I also lost the terminal prompt. Therefore I need to restart the Git bash terminal every test run to regain the terminal prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue by adding the `threads: false,` configuration to the `vitest.config.js` configuration file. The complete content of the configuration file:

```js
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url'
import { mergeConfig, defineConfig, configDefaults } from 'vitest/config'
import viteConfig from './vite.config'

export default mergeConfig(
  viteConfig,
  defineConfig({
    test: {
      environment: 'jsdom',
      exclude: [...configDefaults.exclude, 'e2e/*'],
      root: fileURLToPath(new URL('./', import.meta.url)),
      threads: false, // Add this option to avoid segmentation fault
    }
  })
)
```

Alternatively, you can also run the `vitest` without using threads:

```
vitest --no-threads
```

Reference: https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/317#issuecomment-1542319622